# Show $y^3+xy+x^2(x-1)^2\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have tried applying Eisentein's Criterion to no avail, and I have also tried reducing modulo some proper ideal, with no luck either. Is there some standard way of showing polynomials in two variables are irreducible?

Comment: I think considering the polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x][y]$ and applying the rational root theorem should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x,y)=y^3+xy+x^2(x-1)^2$ and suppose we have the decomposition
$$f(x,y)=g(x,y)h(x,y).$$
Since degree of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ is $3$, then we must have
$$g(x,y)=p(x)y+q(x)\quad \text{and}\quad h(x,y)=r(x)y^2+s(x)y+t(x)$$
where $p(x),q(x),r(x),s(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ are polynomials with degree at most $4$.

Expanding $g(x,y)h(x,y)$ we reach
$$f(x,y)=p(x)r(x)y^3+(p(x)s(x)+q(x)r(x))y^2+(p(x)t(x)+q(x)s(x))y+q(x)t(x)$$
which implies $p(x)=r(x)=1$ are constant polynomials because in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ only constant polynomials are invertible.

Now by comparing coefficient, we see
$$s(x)=-q(x),\quad t(x)=-q(x)s(x)+x,\quad q(x)t(x)=x^2(x-1)^2$$
i.e. $$t(x)=q(x)^2+x$$ and therefore, $$q(x)(q(x)^2+x)=x^2(x-1)^2$$
which is impossible because LHS is a polynomial of degree multiple of $3$.

Comment: How do we know $p(x)=r(x)=1$? Why couldn't we have the constant polynomials $p(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $r(x)=2$?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow What one really gets is that $p$ and $r$ are invertible (and inverses of each other). Therefore, you can divide $g$ by $p$ and multiply $h$ by $p$, which allows you to assume that $p=r=1$ from there after.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps consider mod 6, as then $y^3\equiv y$ and $y(x+1)+x^2(x-1)^2$ is irreducible

Comment: $3x^2+x$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but $x$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: $6$ is a unit in $\mathbb{R}$, so modding out yields the $0$ ring. And even in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x,y]$, we still have $y^3 \neq y$ despite the fact that their values are the same.